# Dynamic @Table name based on input

Tags: java, hibernate, queryinterceptor

We have Hibernate based application where due to a large data set, two sets of tables are created where user_id will either be mapped in the UserTickets table or RestOfWorldTickets table.
Would like to know how @Table on the entity java objects can be dynamically mapped based on some user selection.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "**UserTickets**")
public class UserTickets {

  @Id
  @Column("Internal_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  private int internalId;

  @Column("user_id")
  private int userId;

  @Column("state")
  private String state;

  @Column("city")
  private String city;

  @Column("address")
  private String address;

  @Column("ticketNumber")
  private String ticketNumber;
  ..
  // Setters and Getters 

}

UserTickets DB Table
Internal_id  |  User_id | State  |  City   | Address | ticket_number | ...
101          |  1025    | AZ     |  Tuscan | ..      | 10256912      |
102          |  1026    | NC     |  Durham | ..      | 10256983   

RestOfWorldTickets DB Table
Internal_id  |  User_id | State  |  City   | Address | ticket_number |..
101          |  1058    | {null} |  London | ..      | 102578963     |..
102          |  1059    | {null} |  Berlin | ..      | 112763458     |.. 


The user and table mapping are now defined in a new table.

TableMapping Database table.
Internal_id  | User_id  | TableMapped        |
1            | 1025     | UserTickets        |
2            | 1026     | UserTickets        |
3            | 1058     | RestOfWorldTickets |
4            | 1059     | RestOfWorldTickets |
```

So, using the UserTickets result set, how I map @Table attribute on the UserTickets Java object dynamically so that my Criteria API queries will work automatically without changing them to HQL queries?

Maybe using Interceptors http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html?

Comment: Did i understand correct: You have a user id and you want to make a query with that and based on the id it should be against `UserTickets` or `RestOfWorldTickets`. And you possibly do not want to use the mapping table having _Internal_id  | User_id  | TableMapped_ ?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite unsure what you actually need but i try to give my solution based on a few quesses. Changing `@Table` dynamically is not -afaik- possible but if i guessed right you could have some benefit of inheritance in this case:

**1st** modify `UserTickets` to allow inheritance

```
@Entity
//@Table(name = "**UserTickets**")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class UserTickets {

    @Id // this annotation was missing from yours ? 
    @Column(name="Internal_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
       // identity generated problems in openjpa so i changed it to SEQUENCE
    private int internalId;
    @Column(name="user_id") private int userId;
    @Column(name="state") private String state;
    @Column(name="city") private String city;
    @Column(name="address") private String address;
    @Column(name="ticketNumber") private String ticketNumber;
}
```

**2nd** create a new entity

```
@Entity
public class RestOfWorldTickets extends UserTickets {
   // yes i am just an empty class, TABLE_PER_CLASS gives me the fields
}
```

This allows you to use criteriaqueries against `UserTickets` but in addition the queries are done against `RestOfWorldTickets` also. So now when you search with user id result set will contain results from both tables. Checking/ loggin -for example with `instanceof` operator- you can see which one the ticket is.

"Disclaimer" i am using and testing with `openjpa` so there can be some differences/probkems with this solution...

Comment: Thanks for the reply pirho.. I have updated the name of the 3rd table name to "TableMapping" and I have added @Id attribute to my Java Pojo as well. However, the 'TableMapping' table has clear differentiation to which table the query should would. How to determine dynamically ?  Note: Chances are present that 3rd table can also come up and my java code should route the queries dynamically.